# Openmp thread distribution

Tags: fortran, openmp, fortran90

I am trying to learn openmp ( particularly $omp do ) in Fortran90 and facing a strange problem. I have written a simple code and executing it using 2 processors. I have compiled the program using "gfortran -fopenmp filename.f90".

```
   use omp_lib
   implicit none
   integer :: i,j,a(2)


     write ( *, '(a,i8)' ) &
  '  The number of processors available = ', omp_get_num_procs ( )
     write ( *, '(a,i8)' ) &
  '  The number of threads available    = ', omp_get_max_threads ( )
   !$OMP DO 
   do i = 1, 2
      a(i) = i + 1
      j = OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
      print*,"a(i)=",a(i), "j = ",OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
   enddo
   !$OMP END DO
   end
```

The output I am seeing is

The number of processors available =        6

The number of threads available    =        2

a(i)=           2 j =            0

a(i)=           3 j =            0

But I was expecting variable j to take up values 0 and 1 for i = 1 and i = 2 respectively. Where am I going wrong? My expectation is met if I use $omp do parallel instead of $omp do.

Comment: Without `parallel` the code does not run in parallel, hence both iterations are in the same thread. See also this article: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/32-openmp-traps-for-c-developers#IDAFLQDC

Comment: Thanks Max for the clarification